# How can I uninstall phpPgAdmin?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, phppgadmin

I want to uninstall phpPgAdmin. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is, "How do I prevent phpPgAdmin from running," well, don't let the web server get at it. :)  Just delete it from under the webroot.

If your question is, "How do I change which port I use to get at phpPgAdmin," that's entirely dependent on the web server's configuration; you set it to listen on a different port.

Comment: Updated my question. I would like to uninstall phpPgAdmin. I don't know the location of the folder

Comment: You'll need to find the web root of your web server. That depends on the operating system and the particular web server you are running. If you are running Apache, start by looking for the httpd.conf file.